# NodeJS App becomes non responsive when connected to MongoDB replica set and the primary fails (failover)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I have a REST API (Written with Express + Monk ) connected to MongoDB. The database is a MongoDB replica set setup with mms.

When the primary node goes down the app becomes non responsive. It need a manual restart to work again after the SECONDARY is elected as PRIMARY.

Config :

- Mongodb Replica set (Ver 2.6.7) configured with MMS
- Total three nodes (two data nodes and one arbiter)
- All default configs as given by MMS
- Node App : Express with Monk as mongodb driver. (I tried in mongoose as well,same result)

Connection string :-

```
mongodb://xxx1.xxx.com:27017, xxx2.xxx.com:27017: 27017/dbname    
with option as 
var options = {
server: {
    socketOptions: {
        keepAlive: 1,
        socketTimeoutMS : 15000,
        connectTimeoutMS: 30000
    }
},
replset: {
    socketOptions: {
        keepAlive: 1,
        socketTimeoutMS : 15000,
        connectTimeoutMS: 30000
    }
}
```

}

Is it related to something I misconfigured? Does it have anything to do with mms? How to fox this?

UPDATE:
Steps I followed

1. Created 3 three new VMs in Azure Cloud and deployed mongodb replica set to it using MMS (One primary, one secondary and one arbiter).
2. Generated a new express app.
3. Added Monk module
4. Write a simple API to connect to the replica set (The API will write something to db, then read it and send back as response)
5. Continuously call this API form a bash script to make sure that the API is up and running
6. restart the machine which is acting as primary

The API will keep failing even after a new primary is elected and all VMs are back up.

Comment: Honestly. Adding more tags does not draw "positive" attention to you question. Please keep it relevant otherwise you are just annoying a wider group of people than those who can possibly solve your problem.

Comment: Independent comment to really good advice. Are you actually specifying all possible nodes ( arbiter cannot resolve queries ) in your initial connection url?

Comment: @NeilLunn I think those tags I added are relevant to the question. The issue can be related to either node js driver for mongodb or mongodb config. If you are aware of the issue, please suggest me which tags would work  better. I am not an expert here.

Comment: @NeilLunn no only two data nodes are added in URI

Comment: I don't think they were relevant and this is possibly a fault of how monk implements resolution of a lost host by not following the base schematics of the base node driver. But if you can provide a base test case that proves this then it would be useful content to provide in your question. In your configuration then two nodes should be sufficient. So show us the basic failing case.

Comment: @NeilLunn I tried the same with mongoose driver as well, but getting the same result. 

will update the question with steps i followed.

Comment: @NeilLunn please check the sample code at https://melvingeorge@bitbucket.org/melvingeorge/nodejsmongorssample.git